# Laravel - using onclick to submit form from checkbox

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple task list project under Laravel.

When I click a checkbox it does not show a checked condition. (The second item is in the true condition in the database and thus shows checked. I cannot uncheck this item) I have searched for an answer to why on the net but cannot find a solution or reason.

Code:

home.blade.php (in views folder) -

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')

<h1>Tasks</h1>

<ul>
@foreach ($items as $item)
    <li>
        {{ Form::open() }}
            <input type="checkbox" onClick="this.form.submit()" {{     $item->done ? 'checked' : '' }}>

            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $item->id }}">

            {{ $item->name }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </li>   
@endforeach
</ul>

@stop
```

HomeController.php (inControllers folder) -

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

public function getIndex() {
    $items = Auth::user()->items;

    return View::make('home', array(
        'items' => $items
    ));
}

public function postIndex() {
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $item = Item::findOrFail($id);

    if($item->owner_id == $userId) {
        $item->mark();
    }

    return Redirect::route('home');
}
}
```

Item.php (in models folder) -

```
<?php

class Item extends Eloquent {
public function mark() {
    $this->$done = $this->done ? false : true;

    $this->save();
}
}
```

routes.php -

```
<?php

Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex'))->before('auth');
Route::post('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@postIndex'))->before('csrf');

Route::get('/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'))->before('guest');  
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'AuthController@postLogin'))->before('csrf');
```

Comment: im still not sure what your problem is ... can you explain it in a different way

Comment: I don't know a ton about laravel, but your checkbox doesn't have a name or id attribute so I don't understand how you are accessing the value of that checkbox from your controller.  It looks like you are getting the value of that hidden field below it though.

Answer (score 2):

in your code, you never update the model's *done* value. i assume, you want to change it with the post method. so you'd need to take the value from the checkbox name (e.g. `Input::get('box-ID')`)

you could also create a checkbox using the form class:

```
// public function checkbox($name, $value = 1, $checked = null, $options = array())
{{ Form::checkbox('name', 'value', true, ['onClick' => 'alert(123)']) }}
```

reference: [Formbuilder -> checkbox](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Html.FormBuilder.html#_checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your form like this. It works me I hope will work for you also.

{{ Form::open(['route' => ['items.update', $items->id], 'class' => 'form-inline', 'method' => 'put']) }}

Thanks